# Want to set write preference to MIRROR on Google cloud Platform (BigQuery)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[See from image option to set write preference not available in advanced options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE1Jq.png)

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery doesn't have a write preference as "Mirror", you can see the write preference options [in here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/WriteDisposition). In the BigQuery console, these options are shown in the advanced options according to the source of the table. When the source of the table to be created is an empty table, Drive, Google Cloud Bigtable or Cloud Storage (external table) there are no write preferences available since there is no data that will be written into BigQuery. Please notice that Drive, Bigtable, Cloud Storage (external table) and Cloud SQL are [external data sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources).